# PHP - Apache - MySQL Server | Could not connect to host

Tags: php, mysql, apache, soap, dns

I'm facing this problem since yesterday evening. I have been now over 6 hours on Google, trying to figure out what the solution could be.

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627031/fatal-error-maximum-execution-time-of-30-seconds-exceeded-in-model-php-on-l), setting the timeout on all php.ini files to 300 or unlimited, I have tried setting the buffer of MySQL higher, tried to restart both Apache and MySQL server, ...

**Problem:** What I'm trying to do, where the error occurs, is to execute a SOAP-command (command is correct) `$this -> soap -> executeCommand(new SoapParam($command, 'command'));`, which results in:

`"Could not connect to host"` **--> if I set** `define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');` or

**Problem 2:**

```
 //Warning: mysqli::mysqli() [function.mysqli-mysqli]: (HY000/2003): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blacktempel.dyndns-home.com' (10060) in C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Server_09122014\Apache\_Server\htdocs\SOAPRegistration.php on line 109
 //Warning: mysqli::close() [function.mysqli-close]: Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\Users\NAME\Desktop\Server_09122014\Apache\_Server\htdocs\SOAPRegistration.php on line 154


$this -> db = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME, DB_PORT); //Line 109
$this -> db -> close(); //Line 154
```

`"Database connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'blacktempel.dyndns-home.com' (10060)"` **--> if I set** `define('DB_HOST', 'blacktempel.dyndns-home.com');`.

My firewall is not the problem, I have checked this multiple times.

My hosts file contains this:

```
#       127.0.0.1       localhost
#       ::1             localhost
        MyExternalIp    blacktempel.dyndns-home.com
```

SOAP:

```
define('SOAP_IP', '127.0.0.1');
define('SOAP_PORT', '7878');
```

MySQL is running on port 3306 and listening. My other defines, such as `DB_USER`, `DB_PASS`, are correct.

**Q: Why won't it work ? What could be wrong ? Is there anything I could possibly have missed ?**

Comment: Can you log into mysql via command prompt?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I can.

Comment: Using localhost and 127.0.0.1 or just localhost?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I use(d) both.

Comment: what OS are you using?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah Windows 7

Comment: Does your user have permissions to access the database?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah All permissions which are needed.

Comment: I know your on windows, but this question may be of help to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13769504/mysqlimysqli-hy000-2002-cant-connect-to-local-mysql-server-through-sock  My guess is that PHP does not know about mysql.  Can you connect to another database from the same script?

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I have tried changing the default socket in php.ini, also in my.cnf. I can't connect to another database from the script, no. (using DNS)

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not able to be of more help to you as I'm not sure how to configure your mysql properly.  However, at least you know the problem now.  It won't work because your PHP doesn't know about your MySQL.

Comment: @RaphaelRafatpanah I have now tried to work with a various range of different MySQL and PHP/Apache configurations, also I have tried XAMPP. Nothing has worked, it always fails at the connection to the Database/MySQL-Server. A single `test.php`-file, containing only a connection and close to the database has also failed. I don't know how I should fix this, but I guess I need to find a work-around, as I would need this tomorrow for a test. Normal connections, from HeidiSQL, Navicat, MySQL-Workbench, [...] do work with the user/password settings.

Comment: My recommendation would be to post a new question with a detailed list of what you've tried, your configuration files, and your errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed the issue.

The SOAP problem was caused by a setting in the config file of the program accessed by SOAP.