# how to clear mysql cache inside of stored procedure?

Tags: mysql, performance, caching, stored-procedures, procedure

how to clear mysql cache inside of stored procedure?
I have mysql store procedure called test2.i execute it using another store procedure called test1. test 1 have for each loop and inside of that loop I execute test2. if loop have only one round its get 34.294 sec for execute. if loop have 30 rounds it get 1360.641 sec. that the reason for above question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clear MySQL query cache without restarting server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5231678/clear-mysql-query-cache-without-restarting-server)

Comment: @P.Salmon i already try that one but not work. I am not 100% sure is it cache problem.but my scenario is it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking about the query cache, simply do

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE ...
```

to avoid *that* cache.

If you are asking about the buffer_pool, so state.  *They are very different.*